# Как получить параметры request'a при enctype="multipart/form-data" в сервлете Java?

Tags: java, html, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Есть POST запрос. Для наглядности, если бы это был GET запрос, то URL выглядел бы так:

```
http://localhost:8080/tasks?file=1x.jpg&operation=ADD
```

Необходимо вытащить параметры запроса, а также загрузить файл. Если не указать `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, загрузка не будет работать (через `req.getParts()`), а если указать, то при попытке получить параметр получаем `null`:

```
String operationString = req.getParameter("operation); //null
```

Как можно при `enctype="multipart/form-data"` вытащить параметры request'a?

Comment: Вам надо отображать фотография на браузере? и добавить фотография?

Comment: Мне нужно загрузить файл(в данном случае jpg) на сервер

Comment: <input type="file" name="name"> в jsp։ место name добавьте ваш параметр который вы дали  request param на multipartFile

Comment: <input type="file" id="file" name="file" style="display:none;"/> Также есть и другие input. НО если enctype="multipart/form-data" не добавлен в form, то я не могу загружать файл на сервер при помощи req.getParts(), если же добавить в форму enctype, то не могу получить req.getParamater("file"), выдает null при enctype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте библиотеку [`Apache Commons FileUpload`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/index.html)

Форма:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="fup.cgi">
  File to upload: <input type="file" name="upfile"><br/>
  Notes about the file: <input type="text" name="note"><br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Press"> to upload the file!
</form>
```

Получение файла (можно использовать как в фильтре так и в сервлете):

```
// Create a factory for disk-based file items
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

// Configure a repository (to ensure a secure temp location is used)
ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
File repository = (File) servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
factory.setRepository(repository);

// Create a new file upload handler
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

// Parse the request
List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);

Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItem item = iter.next();

    if (item.isFormField()) {
        // Достаём поле формы
        processFormField(item);
    } else {
        // Достаём файл
        processUploadedFile(item);
    }
}
```

Пример кода взят [отсюда](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html)

Comment: Спасибо! Есть еще один способ: указать enctype="multipart/form data", на сервлете использовать аннотацию @Multipart. Тогда картинка передаваться будет, параметры тоже можно получать корректно КРОМЕ параметра file из моего примера. Его можно вытащить через getPart("file"); При помощи самописного парсера вытащить имя и использовать part.write(String absPath) загрузить на сервер.